# My livefeed reloads every 30 seconds. How stop refresh when playing video?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, refresh

I've made a live-feed for my website. Every 30 seconds the content reloads. But now I have a problem. When I'm adding an embedded video (from Youtube) or an HTML5 `<video>`, I can't play the video completely because of the reload. Is it possible to stop the auto reload when the video is playing, and restart the reload when the video has stopped?

This is what I use for the reload:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#updates").load("updates.php");
    var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
        $("#updates").load('updates.php' + '?randval=' + Math.random());
    }, 30000);
    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
    });
});
```

You can video my live-feed here.

Comment: Look into the API, https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference  Capture statechange, clear interval in case video is playing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is untested. One thing beforehand - you can't handle an html5 video element the same way like an embedded youtube iframe. 
In case you have a video element you can interact directly with it and use the eventhandlers for play, pause and end to handle your request. A possible solution could look something like this:

```
$(function() {
    var refreshId;
    // collection of all video elements on your page
    var videos = $('video');

    // disable reload by clearing the interval
    function blockReload() {
        clearInterval(refreshId);
    }

    // your existing reload function
    function startReload() {
        refreshId = setInterval(function() {
            $("#updates").load('updates.php' + '?randval=' + Math.random());
        }, 30000);
    }

    // loop over all video elements on your page and bind
    // three event handlers, one for playing, one for pausing
    // and one for an ended video.
    videos.each(function() {
        this.addEventListener('playing', blockReload);
        this.addEventListener('paused', startReload);
        this.addEventListener('ended', startReload);
    });
});
```

Since you can't control embedded elements directly, you'll need to work with the [youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference). 
Instead of using the iframe from youtube, you use the API to load the video like this (example from the API page):

```
// This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
// you could also use a normal script tag in that case you would load 
// the lib each time.
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
```

Next you load the video via the script library:

```
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    height: '360'
    width: '640',
    videoId: 'YOURVIDEOID',
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
}
```

Now you can interact with the youtube video:

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
  // check if video is running...
  if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
    // disable interval
    blockReload();
  } else {
    // restart interval
    startReload();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found  this solution by trial and error (I used axel.michel's functions `Blockreload()` and `StartReload()`).

You can add `onplay=""` and `onended=""` to the video-tag (it also works for the audio-tag). `onplay=""` loads the function `Blockreload()`, `onended=""` loads the function `StartReload()`.

It looks like this:

```
<video id="test" onplay="BlockReload()" onended="StartReload()" width="800" controls>
   <source src="*video source*"> 
   Jouw browser ondersteund onze videoplayer niet. 
</video>
```

Comment: axel.michel's work looks helpful, so I suggest giving him or her an upvote for their time and effort, given that it led you to a solution.